# Installing Camomile via opam fails due to missing patch file. How can I fix this?

Tags: ocaml, opam, camomile

While installing [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop) via [opam](http://opam.ocaml.org) on my ArchLinux laptop, I got the following message:

```
$ opam install utop
The following actions will be performed:
 - install camomile.0.8.5 [required by utop]
 - install zed.1.3 [required by utop]
 - install lambda-term.1.6 [required by utop]
 - install utop.1.14
4 to install | 0 to reinstall | 0 to upgrade | 0 to downgrade | 0 to remove
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] 

=-=-= Installing camomile.0.8.5 =-=-=
Applying cmxs.patch.

[ERROR] Due to some errors while processing camomile.0.8.5, the following actions will NOT proceed:
 - install utop.1.14
 - install lambda-term.1.6
 - install zed.1.3

===== ERROR while installing camomile.0.8.5 =====
Could not get the source for camomile.0.8.5:
# opam-version    1.1.1
# os              linux
Patch file "/home/sinan/.opam/system/build/camomile.0.8.5/cmxs.patch" not found.
'opam install utop' failed.
```

Trying to install [camomile](https://github.com/yoriyuki/Camomile/tree/master/Camomile) by itself also gives the same error. This seems to be related to [commit 672e44e](https://github.com/yoriyuki/Camomile/commit/672e44e) which carried over to the `opam` repository as [cmxs.patch](https://github.com/jpdeplaix/opam-repository/blob/f5917cd5dc431583327a07857b768a6f73122d63/packages/camomile/camomile.0.8.5/files/cmxs.patch). I am not sure where things break so that `opam` tries to build without the patch file.

I tried downloading, and putting `cmxs.patch` in the reported location, but, of course, that directory gets clobbered the next time I try to install via `opam`.

How should I proceed?

Comment: you can download the file from the opam-repository and place it in the opam path (.opam/packages/camomile/camomile.0.8.5/files/cmxs.patch). Maybe opam update will refresh things --but I imagine you've done that already.

Comment: ah! I was placing it in the `build` directory. I'll try that when I back on that computer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have preferred to have been able to fix the underlying problem, but, in the end, downloading the [contents of the cmxs.patch file](https://github.com/jpdeplaix/opam-repository/blob/f5917cd5dc431583327a07857b768a6f73122d63/packages/camomile/camomile.0.8.5/files/cmxs.patch), adding it to the already downloaded `~/.opam/archives/camomile.0.8.5+opam.tar.gz` archive, and then issuing

```
$ opam install camomile
```

worked.

After that, `opam install utop` went without a hitch as well.

For your reference, I have:

```
$ opam --version
1.1.1
```

```
$ cat .opam/repo/default/repo 
upstream: "https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/tree/master/"
browse: "https://opam.ocaml.org/pkg/"
```

Comment: Are you pointing to an old version of the opam-repository? What version of OPAM are you using? The file is mentioned in `https://opam.ocaml.org/urls.txt`, so it is peculiar this isn't working.